# How to import modules from different files ifor VSCode dynamically?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am having an issue with VSCode. I tested the same directory and files in PyCharm and I don't need to write another code to recognize my modules. The interpreter immediately runs the code. I just need to use i.e. `from folder_module import module as np`. In VSCode this is very complex and after a lot of research in the internet I didn't find any helpful solution.

I don't want to use `sys.path.append('datapath_folder')` (which works) or any similar solution because I will transfer the files into another computer. I use python 3.8.4. How can I import from different files?

My test files:

```
Python Modules
    - ModulesImport
        -  main.py
    - TestFile
        - mymodule.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing modules in VSCode, VSCode searches for modules from the parent folder by default. so if they are not the same parent folder, VSCode cannot automatically find the modules that need to be imported.

If you don't want to change the added folder path('`datapath_folder`'), it is recommended that you add the following code to the beginning of the file. It adds the file that needs to be imported to the system path so that VSCode can find it. (It does not need to change any folder path)

> ```
> import os,sys 
> sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
> ```

[image]

Update:

If importing classes in other scripts, we can use "`.`" to indicate the files and folders of the class: (The above statement can also be used.)

[image]

(class: `class_aa` in `main.py`)

Comment: Yes it works now, there is no need to add folder path every time manully. Is the same method with classes?

Comment: @HeuristicPointer -Yes, it can also be used, but the import statement will be different, I updated my answer and you can refer to it.

Comment: It seems that intepreter does not recognize subfolders i.e.  a -> b, c and throws me an error ```Import "TestFile2" could not be resolved Pylance ```, but it compiles the code normally.

Comment: @HeuristicPointer -You can try adding "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["----extension-pkg-whitelist=1xml"] in "settings.json".

Comment: No it doesn't work. I am afraid that depends on Pylance functionality, from what I am reading. They fixed the bug issue only for main folders but not for main file subfolders. I added just ```"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
            "reportMissingImports": "none"
        }``` to override the import report. Secondly by importing  ```mymodule as md``` loses its color.